# Mobile Responsive

Tags: html, css

I need help in coming up with a creative idea/way to transform the carousel indicators into a menu or any other possible way of making the whole section mobile responsive with all the indicators present within the mobile width. I have tried multiple ways that haven't worked. I am kinda new to programming where I wanted to challenge myself but making it responsive became difficult for me. As you can see when running the code, day one is not visible and also day 8 is overlapping. I'll be happy to get a solution for a project I am doing.

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

a,
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -ms-transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  -o-transition-duration: .2s;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

span,
a,
a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*==========================
      history area
===========================*/

.section-title,
.column-title {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #101010;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.section-title span,
.column-title span {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.title-small {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.column-title {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.column-title-large {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.ts-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.title-light {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.title-small-regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.black-color {
  color: #101010 !important;
}

.title-white {
  color: #fff;
}

.title-bg-small {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #101010;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.primary-bg {
  background: #e80000;
}

.history-area {
  background: #f7f9fb;
  padding: 100px 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#history-slid .history-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

#history-slid .carousel-inner {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

#history-slid .carousel-item {
  background: #fff;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  z-index: -1;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0 35px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #101010;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #101010;
  margin-left: -7px;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators li.active {
  line-height: 35px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  color: #e80000;
  background: #fff;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators li.active::before {
  background: #e80000;
}

#history-slid .carousel-indicators li.active:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -34px;
  left: 44%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  border: 1px solid #e80000;
}

#history-slid .carousel-item-next,
#history-slid .carousel-item-prev,
#history-slid .carousel-item.active {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section class="history-area">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <p class="title-bg-small wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="300ms">Beach Trip</p>
        <h3 class="section-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="400ms">Our
          <span>Itinerary</span></h3>
      </div>
      <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="history-slid" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/CKNmhMX/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/m5yGbdR/blog2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/YXV3zmh/blog3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row active">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/CKNmhMX/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/m5yGbdR/blog2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/YXV3zmh/blog3.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/CKNmhMX/blog1.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
            <div class="carousel-item row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pl-0">
                <div class="history-img">
                  <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/m5yGbdR/blog2.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 pr-0">
                <div class="history-content">
                  <p class="title-bg-small primary-bg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="500ms">
                    Lorem ipsum</p>
                  <h2 class="column-title wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="700ms">Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span></h2>
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    Benefit of the socie where we operate. A success website obusly needs great design to be one of the top 10 IT companies in India but the web design is not enough.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End off item-->
          </div>
          <!-- End off carusel inner -->
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators text-center">
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="0">Day 1</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="1">Day 2</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="2">Day 3</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="3" class="active">Day 4</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="4">Day 5</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="5">Day 6</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="6">Day 7</li>
            <li data-target="#history-slid" data-slide-to="7">Day 8</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

hanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which you need is to change display of your list to flex.

```
@media screen and (max-width:990px){   
 .carousel-indicators{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hamid. I tried that, but personally didn't like it as much but it looks okay. I was thinking of a single indicator to be present then, next and previous buttons to appear so that when one clicks on them the next slide appears with the indicator tag changing eg. from day 1 to day 2 aligned in the middle. I don't know if it's possible but it anyone manages I'll be happy :-). Am still trying some ideas where if it works, I'll share.